# How to automatically fill a column with spaces to a pre-determined length?

Tags: postgresql, types, pattern-matching

I am wondering how I can manipulate a column type = integer to return a pre-determined length of 10 even if the actual value only has a length of 4. The delta should be filled with spaces.

To be specific:

column: `last_id`;
exemplary value: `101223`;
length of integer: `SELECT length(id::text)` = 6

Thus it should add 4 spaces. If the length of the integer is 5 it should 5 spaces.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT lpad(last_id::text, 10, ' ')  -- pad left
     , rpad(last_id::text, 10, ' ')  -- pad right
     , last_id::char(10)             -- trick to pad right
```

The manual has more on [String Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) and on [character types like `char(n)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).